# how to show username instead of user id using xlwt

Tags: python, django, xlwt

Am exporting data to excel using `xlwt` but the problem that am getting user id in the row user instead of username, how to fix this,, here is the view

```
def export_buy_and_sell_report_csv(request):
    today_date = date.today()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="BuyAndSellReports_' + str(today_date) + '.xls"'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('BuyAndSells')
    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    columns = ['المستخدم', ' القيمة', 'البيان', 'الفئة', 'نوع الحركة', 'التاريخ']
    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)
    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    rows = models.BuyAndSellReport.objects.all().values_list('user', 'amount', 'text', 'move_category', 'move_type',
                                                             'date')
    rows = [[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x for x in row] for row in
            rows]
    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to access a specific property of user instead of using a foreign key in values_list.

Try constructing your query like this:

```
rows = models.BuyAndSellReport.objects.all().values_list('user__username', 'amount', 'text', 'move_category', 'move_type',
                                                         'date')
```